# custom background for icefaces stacked line chart

Tags: css, jsf, icefaces

Hello I am working with JSF and Icefaces stacked line graphs [Icefaces showroom](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=ace:chart&exp=Custom%20Color). I made it look as follows.
[image: sample single chart]

Because I needed the green, yellow and red lines to indicate some kind of performance indicator. I simply applied custom gradients to the `background` of class `jqplot-series-canvas` which renders the chart series like this.

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 9%,#fc775f 9%,#ffffff 10%,#ffffff 19%,#f4f400 19%,#ffffff 20%,#ffffff 39%,#37e837 40%,#37e837 40%,#ffffff 40%,#ffffff 100%);
```

My code for the simple `.xhtml` looks as follows,

```
<ace:chart id="memoryChart"
     animated="false"
     value="#{chartColorBean.fillData}"
     xAxis="#{chartColorBean.xAxis}"
     yAxes="#{chartColorBean.yAxes}"
     stackSeries="true"
     defaultSeriesColors="#{chartColorBean.customDefaultColor}"
     legend="#{chartColorBean.legend}"
     legendPlacement="INSIDE_GRID"
     highlighter="true"
     highlighterLocation="N"
     highlighterShowMarker="false"
     highlighterBringSeriesToFront="true"/>
```

After rendering the html code looks like this,

[image]

Now the problem is that when I add another line graph in the same chart, because of the background property, only the line series on top is visible, the other one gets hidden. How do I implement this correctly?